# Porque no me muestra el numero 2 como numero primo

Tags: python-3.8

Estoy haciendo una funcion para detectar numeros primos y no me funciona con el numero 2:

```
def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,num):
        valor=True
        while valor:
            if i!=2:
                if num%i==0:#
                    valor = True
                    return False
                else:
                    valor = False
                    return True
            elif i==2:
                valor = False
                return True
```

Comment: por que tu al hacer `range(2,num)` y si num vale 2 es `range(2,2)` y no hay numeros entre 2 y 2

Answer (score 1):

Una forma simplificada de hacerlo es la siguiente.

```py
def isPrime2(num):
    init_prime = [2,3,5,7]
    if num in init_prime: return True
    flag = None
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i == 0:
            flag = False
            break
        else: flag = True
    return flag
```

La lista `init_prime` contiene algunos de los primeros números primos, luego existe una variable llamada `flag` que es como un marcador, el cual tendrá el valor de `True` o `False` según corresponda.

**test**
Hice un test con los 100 primeros números primos para ver que todo funcione Ok

```
primos = []
for n in range(1,101):
    if isPrime2(n): primos.append(n)

numeros = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

if primos == numeros: print("yes")
else: print("nop")
```

**resultado**

```
yes
```

Significa que todos los nueros catalogados como primos fueron correctos.

Answer (score 0):

el codigo que soluciona esto es:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num==2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2,num):
            valor=True
            while valor:
                if num%i==0:#
                    valor = True
                    return False
                else:
                     valor = False
                     return True
```

Comment: tu función esta mal `isPrime(6)` retorna `True`

Comment: `isPrime(1)` sale `none`

Comment: @Christian acabo de ejecutar con 6 y sale False.

Comment: había probado el código de la pregunta >_<

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad responder sólo con código. Te recomiendo que repases [answer] y edites tu respuesta para agregar una explicación a tu código. Saludos

Comment: el @Bicho el número 1 no es primo ni compuesto